# How to do the program that able to show the top 10 keywords in text file, in python

Tags: python

i am working on the program that able to show the top 10 keywords in the text file. The following are the step that i already did:

1. open the file
2. do the list of pairs
3. and sorted the pairs

after sorted my program got error. the paragraph below is my code.

```
filename = 'alice.txt'

try:
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f_obj:
        contents = f_obj.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    msg = 'Sorry, the file ' + filename + 'does not exist. '
    print(msg)
else:
    words = contents.split()

    
wordfreq = []
for w in words:
    wordfreq.append(words.count(w))
    

pairs = str(list(zip(words, wordfreq) ))
for key , value in pairs.items():
    print("Pairs\n" + str(list(zip(words, wordfreq))))
    
#print("Frequencies\n" + str(wordfreq) + "\n")
#print("Pairs\n" + str(list(zip(words, wordfreq))))    
#print(max(str(list(zip(words, wordfreq)))))
    


#print(max(int(list(wordfreq,words))))
  
    
#print("List\n" + str(words) + "\n")

#    num_words = len(words)
#    print("The file " + filename + " has about " + str(num_words) + " words. ")
```

Comment: Could you describe more the issue you're facing? What error do you have, if any? What output do you get? What do you expect to have?

Comment: Look into collections.Counter()

Answer (score 1):

The first problem seems to be you've chosen the wrong data type for your word to frequency 'pairing'.
So I've fixed it and modded it a little bit into a form that should get you a big closer to your answer, please provide more specific information about your problem.

```
filename = 'alice.txt'

try:
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f_obj:
        contents = f_obj.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    msg = 'Sorry, the file ' + filename + 'does not exist. '
    print(msg)
else:
    words = contents.split()

wordfreq = []
for w in words:
    wordfreq.append(words.count(w))

pairs = dict(zip(words, wordfreq))
for key, value in pairs.items():
    print(f"Pairs\n {key}, {value}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your `list` to a `set`, you can identify the unique words in the text. Then by making a `zip` you can use `sorted` to sort the words based on the frequency of their appearance in the text.

```
filename = 'alice.txt'

try:
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f_obj:
        contents = f_obj.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    msg = 'Sorry, the file ' + filename + 'does not exist. '
    print(msg)
else:
    words = contents.split()

words_set = set(words)

wordfreq = []
for w in words_set:
    wordfreq.append(words.count(w))

pairs = zip(words_set, wordfreq)

sorted_pairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

for w, wq in sorted_pairs:
    print("'{}' appears {} times.".format(w, wq))
```